# $\Omega^1_{B/A}=0$ then $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f\colon (A,\mathfrak{p})\longrightarrow (B,\mathfrak{q})$ be a homomorphism of local rings. I have to check that if $\Omega^1_{B/A}=0$ then $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}B$.

**REMARK:** I'm not sure if to prove the claim we need that $B$ is finitely generated over $A$ and if we need the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: Can you write down a definition of $\Omega^1$? This should follow fairly quickly from examining the relations imposed by the definition.

Comment: I think that $f$ is injective is not important since you can reduce to this case by the sequences for Kähler differentials. The result seems to be true if in addition $f$ is of finite type (i.e. if $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algbra).

Comment: Thanks. However I proved the claim (as you noticed the injectivity of $f$ is not important).